# Link to all posts page?

Tags: admin

So I have my admin bar hidden by default, because it's ugly, instead of writing a bunch of if statements so certain elements to the WP-admin panel only appear for logged in users, so far so good.

The one I'm having trouble with is the 'all posts' screen, the url is wp-admin/edit.php, yet that gives me a 404 error.

This works, takes the user to the new post screen.

```
<?php 
            global $user_login;
            get_currentuserinfo(); 
            if ($user_login) :
            ?>
            <div class="sectionblocktwo">
                <div class="writeurl">

                    <a href="/wp-admin/post-new.php">Write</a>

                </div> <!-- end div loginurl -->

            </div><!-- end div sectionblocktwo -->

        <?php endif; ?>
```

This does not work.
This only fails to work when on the single.php, since it's an looking for the url sitename.com/single-post-name/wp-admin/edit.php, the other links work fine on single pages.

```
              <?php 
        global $user_login;
        get_currentuserinfo(); 
        if ($user_login) :
    ?>
        <div class="sectionblocktwo">
            <div class="loginurl">

                <a href="wp-admin/edit.php">My Posts</a>

            </div> <!-- end div loginurl -->

        </div><!-- end div sectionblocktwo -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Is there some php code or something I can use to link to the all posts part of the dashboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 2nd example omits the leading `/` in the URL -- does `/wp-admin/edit.php` work?

Also, you're wiser to use [`admin_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/admin_url), since it's possible to change the Admin URL to something other than `/wp-admin`.  Instead of `<a href="/wp-admin/edit.php">`, use `<a href="<?php echo( admin_url( 'edit.php' ) ); ?>">`.  It's more complicated, but much safer.

Comment: Perfect, didn't know about admin url, thank you.